# PowerBI Custom Visuals: Show Dataview Icon doesn't response

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am following the [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/develop-circle-card) to study PowerBI custom visuals. However, I got stuck on the show dataview icon. In the tutorial, when developer clicks the show dataview icon, it should return the following:[Microsoft tutorial screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jCdj.png). But what I got is nothing if I click the show dataview icon: [My powerBI screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iPSy.png).

To fix this, I tried to restart the session, re-build the project... but none of them works.